# Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I've seen a lot of questions about removing the border of a PopupWindow by passing null or new Drawable() to setBackgroundDrawable().  I'm having the opposite problem.  I want a border around my PopupWindow, preferably with a tooltip arrow pointing to my anchor.  Currently, my PopupWindow has no border.  I've tried adjusting the margins, the background in the xml, the width and height of the layout, listview, and listview rows to no avail.  Can someone please help me get a border and an image on the top?  I'm trying to stick with the android SDK with this.

popup_menu_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.jeremiemartinez.refreshlistview.RefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_list_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
private void displayPopupMenu() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu_list, null);        
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        RefreshListView myListView = (RefreshListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_list_listview);       
        mAdapter = new myAdapter(this, getAdapterData());       
        myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);            
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mMyAnchor);      
    }
```

I just grabbed these as examples, but I want something like this where the popup points to the anchor:

[image]

But I get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Edited with example of desired look of PopupWindow

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are many libraries and codes available into Market. Links are given below:

This is the QuickAction UI pattern. Take a look at:

1. [QuickAction-Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)
2. [Quick-action-pattern-in-Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme)
3. [Chrome Style Help Popups](http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.ro/2012/08/blog-post_29.html)

Another alternative would be "super-tooltips":

https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

Here's a demo of it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.supertooltips

From that first link/example looks like below image.
These are just demos, but you can customize as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Sir , the link u gave its says dependency in eclipse

Comment: https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

THis is the link I dont know how to add dependency

Comment: @tushar.narang first you need to add this library in your workspace and then reference library  in your project

Comment: Sir m relatively new ,  can u gimme a link to do this

Comment: For **SuperToolTip** Make sure it's inside a `RelativeLayout` and not `LinearLayout`.

Comment: shame this isn't monitored anymore

Comment: Yes this repo is 'Discontinued'. Is there anything newer made for current Android versions, or in an official Google library?

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking for a simple library, I created one based on PopupWindow.

https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip

[image: Demo]

Comment: Hi @Douglas Nassif Roma Junior , I have checked your library and its great. Could you please tell me how could i make it work on Dialog. Thanks

Comment: The current version of sample project has an example of how to use with Dialogs. [Take a look](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip/blob/11255b06884b81973d61399c495983ec49380733/sample/src/main/java/io/github/douglasjunior/androidSimpleTooltip/sample/MainActivity.java#L219)

Comment: Hi, It works great for API 26, but shows tooltip at wrong location on screen for APIs below 26. Can you please suggest a possible cause or fix for that?

Comment: See the [known-issues](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip#known-issues)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use PopupWindow with view with vector background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:viewportHeight="162"
    android:viewportWidth="196">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/black"
        android:pathData="M0 26.9917C0 12.0846 12.09433 0 26.99583 0L169.0042 0C183.9136 0 196 12.09104 196 26.9917L196 100.0083C196 114.9154 183.9057 127 169.0042 127L124 127L98.5 162L73 127L26.99583 127C12.08644 127 0 114.909 0 100.0083L0 26.9917" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Can you please post same vector image but up arrow

Answer (score 4):

For ***Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher*** you can use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tooltipText="Send an email" />
```

And in your code:

```
// Kotlin
val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
fab.tooltipText = "Some tooltip"
```

```
// Java
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setTooltipText("Some tooltip");
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

This library provides a lightweight, popup like tooltips, fully customizable with an arrows and animations. 100% Kotlin with all necessary documentation. It is actively being managed as well.

Here are some gif from their page;

[image: e]

another,

[image: e]

Answer (score 2):

A more in depth answer can be found at [https://github.com/florent37/ViewTooltip](https://github.com/florent37/ViewTooltip?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5878) which allows you to control many things including the direction from your view. A discussion and some methods can be found [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5878#!description).

**Edit:**
Here's an example gif:
[image]

Comment: gradle cannot compile it

Comment: Works well for position BOTTOM, but doesn't work for position TOP .

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom  tooltip by using xml only. I wrote a demo https://github.com/nidhinek/android-tooltip based on PopupWindow

Answer (score 0):

I also create library in Compose to do something like this:
https://github.com/MarcinKap/Compose-Animation-Tooltips-Library