# Android add floating dialog

Tags: android

I need a floating dialog, pointing to a view.
When view is clicked, it opens. When clicked on screen away from dialog, it is closing.

Please, give me an idea of how to implement such dialog?
Or even better, give me link to lib, that can do this. I ggogled only AlertDialog analogs, but they would not work here

[image]

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow/21153189#21153189](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow/21153189#21153189)

Comment: there are open source libraries available on github for this purpose.
May be following links are helpful to you
https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips, https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips

Comment: This is referred to as ToolTip