# How to show connected dialog on click on View?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

Web version of app has dialog like this.

[image]

Is there any library to implement such connected to view, dialog in Android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QuickActions`

> Quick action pattern is a way of making the applications more
>   interesting and interactive for the users. It is a context menu that
>   doesn't cover up the data that is being acted on. Most of time, this
>   Quick actions dialog is not present in the android by default, so you
>   have to create it.

The **QuickActions** dialog is not included in standard Android SDK, so you have to create it manually .

Read official guideline **[A closer look at Android’s evolving UI patterns](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html)**

You can check Git Demo

1. **[NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)**
2. **[Android PopupWindow with Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow)** #SO
3. **[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](https://androidcoders.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)**
4. **[How to implement quick action pattern in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-quick-action-pattern-in-android/26980)**

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Use PopupWindow to show the dialog:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view);
PopupWindow popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popUpWindow.setContentView(view);
popUpWindow.showAsDropDown(button);
```