# How to make validation for EditText in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have some edit Text and some validation on 
them but when I enter "JJJJ@GMAil.cOM" it except and also for "JJJJ@JJj.com".
how do I do validation for that
here is code:-

```
public boolean validation(String mobile, String pass) {

    if (mobile != null && mobile.length() > 7 && mobile.length() < 15) {
        if (pass.length() >= 4 && pass.length() <= 8) {
            return true;
        } else {
            m_InputPassword.setError("Password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        m_InputMobile.setError("Mobile number must be between 7 to 15 characters long");
        return false;
    }
}   

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

    String regExpn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@" + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?" + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?" + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|" + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: use tooltip : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="true" ,put this n check

Comment: editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {} you cal that validation method inside this listener. Try this also...

Comment: pls follow this: http://pastebin.com/300F3KvJ

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean field for every `EditText` associated, so now you can do the validation and set one of this booleans to `true` if there was an error, then you just you'll has to set an `OnClickListener()` for every `EditText` and if one of this has its associated boolean to true, set the error for it inside listener.