# How to create help buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android

I currently have a homescreen with three buttons. I would like to add a small button on the side of each button that when clicked would pop up a some sort of pop-up, that would explain the functionality of each button. Is there a built-in function for this? Or is this more like a tool-tip?
Thank you

Comment: You could simply use `ImageButton` in the side of each button

Comment: @TheLearner Check this question out (Tooltip) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow

Comment: @Shank Thank you! I believe this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android AlertDialog Box. Android provides default alert box and you can also make you own custom alert box. Just put dialog box in your help button onClick event.

**Reference :**

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
2. http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-custom-dialog-example

Comment: Thank you this looks like a great option. Do you also know if this is possible with a tool tip?

Comment: sorry i don't but there are many tutorials on web you can use it.