# How to change image in imageview after 2 seconds from server in android?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

I have an app in which I have an `ImageView` in that `ImageView` I want to show `image` from server after `2 seconds` .How can I do that.

Comment: use handler to do so

Comment: have some code sample ....I really apreciate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) that executes the change you want (I suppose it will be changing an `ImageView`'s bitmap), and post them with delay to the main thread loop, using a `Handler` and its [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method.

To make it a loop, you could have the `runnable` post itself.

**UpDate :**

This way you can open Activity inside `Handler`.

```
final View imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Intent intent = new Intent(LoActivity.this, StartActivity.class);

                  -- For getting image form ImageView and Pass to Another Activity code --

                     imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                      Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

                     Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                     extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
                     intent.putExtras(extras);

             -- In upper Bundle you have your bitmap Image --

                    LoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    LoActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);
```

and In **AnotherActivity.java** you will get the `bitmap` like this way.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

image.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: let suppose three images are added in image view after 2 seconds when ever user click on image view I want to open another activity wit that image details .is this possible ,if yes guide me plsss.

Comment: means you want to open Activity on `Image` click.

Comment: Images are changing in imageview every after 2 seconds

Comment: I want when user click on imageview he will be redirected to another activity with that image that was clicked by him

Comment: see i have posted code in that code pass the image bitmap before `startActivity` it will hold your `Image` inside `Intent` and in other Activity you can get it via `Bundle`.

Comment: but where is bitmap before startactivity

Comment: @vishwas simple you are getting image from server and then you have to set it to `ImageView` you have code that and get the `Image` from `ImageView` using this code `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`. and pass that `bitmap` to `AnotherActivity`.

Comment: @vishwas I write almost all code you have add only fetch the image from server and it's work..Now do it Happy Coding...

Comment: ok one more thing Is there any way to make pop up window with arrow

Comment: can you show me the `Image` so that I can help you.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=image+with+arrow+pop+up+window&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh74Cb-uDNAhUKlJQKHbylDPYQsAQIHw&biw=1366&bih=643#imgrc=DS-LHijowFRvjM%3A

Comment: I want like yhis pop up over image view showing features about that image text in that pop up will change according to image in imageview

Comment: @vishwas  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow

Comment: @vishwas you can use other answer below have also very nice Answer and it can help you to do that..