# How to create menu over selected text in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, contextmenu

How can i get Text selection menu like below over selected text on webview , i have already tried adding android context action bar [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391169/6478047) but it is not customizable and not working on lower version of android.I Also tried [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow) ways to show menu as a popup but don't know how to attach popup to selected text.Is there any other way to do it? 
or

can it be acheived by using javascript?

[image: like this]