# Tooltip in Items within RecyclerView (Overlap above items)

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a `RecyclerView` with multiple `ViewTypes`. However, on some of the items, I need to display a `Tooltip` which should hover over the above row.

My requirement is:
[image]

In the above image, there are 4 items in the `RecyclerView`, and the tooltip in the lower row should overlap on top of the above row (or rows, as required). This tooltip would only be visible in some scenarios - when the lock icon is visible.

The problem is, if I add this tooltip as a `TextView` to the `row_layout.xml`, and control it's visibility programmatically, it increases the height of that row and does not overlap onto the above layout.

How can I get this view to "hover" over the above rows without displacing them?

If you require code, I can edit this question and post the code too (but I think it might not be necessary here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of **[Android Tooltips](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4253)** library.

Simple to use customizable Android Tooltips library based on [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4253). This Tooltips does not require any custom layout. It works as [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4253).

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.vihtarb:tooltip:0.1.9'
}
```

usage:

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip.Builder(anchorView)
    .setText("Hello tooltip")
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it will work for recycler view ,but for list view you can use quick action item, complete article is over [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/521455/quick-action-pattern-in-android-and-simple-impleme) also look at these [Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow) some of them may work for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library [Super Tooltips](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5048)

It is simple to use and powerful.