# Custom design SeekBar in android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have done the seekbar but I need to do the customization like the below image.

I used the code like this

```
<SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekbarPoints"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small"
                        android:max="0"
                        android:progress="0"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_seekbar_points_style"
                        android:thumb="@null" />

if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(maxPoints)) {
            int maxP = Integer.parseInt(maxPoints);
            mBinding.seekbarPoints.setMax(maxP);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(points)) {
                int p = (int) Double.parseDouble(points);
                mBinding.seekbarPoints.setProgress(p);
            }
        }
mBinding.seekbarPoints.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.shape_seekbar_points_style));
```

In this image there should be a current points showing textView like the image below

[image]

Please suggest some solution for this 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following library to achieve your goal
take a look below libray

- [Library 1](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar)
- [Library 2](https://github.com/masankin/PaginationSeekBar)
- [Library 3](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar)
- [Library 4](https://github.com/woxingxiao/BubbleSeekBar)

Comment: I don't need to slide the bar just I need to add the fixed text with that specific percentage. 
So text should show permanently..

Comment: @CarinaMj than use tool tip

Comment: Can you provide me a sample?

Comment: @CarinaMj follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917557/how-to-implement-a-small-popup-with-some-images-on-a-button-click/44917610#44917610