# How to make a horizontal ContextMenu?

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

I have made an `Activity` called `Accounts` and I want to add a horizontal `ContextMenu`. This may look like the cut, copy and paste options. Is there any way to add this horizontal custom menu `onLongClick` on the list items?

Here's what I've got so far.

```
@Override      
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater().from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, null, false);
    menu.setHeaderView(view);
    menu.add("Delete");
    menu.add("Edit");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    View v = listView.getChildAt(position);
    TextView typeTv = v.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_type);
    TextView userTv = v.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_user);
    TextView passTv = v.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_password);

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
        db.execSQL("delete from user_added_accounts where accountType = '" + typeTv.getText().toString() + "' and username = '" + userTv.getText().toString() + "';");
        recreate();
    }

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Edit")) {
        update(typeTv.getText().toString(), userTv.getText().toString(), passTv.getText().toString());
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the current UI looks like this.

[image: Present working condition]

Here is something like I want,

[image]

Comment: `But I want something standard` What do you consider a *"standard"* approach? Alternatively, what is non-standard?

Comment: I want a  better way.

Comment: Please define what do you mean with "better". The "standard way" is a [vertical contextual menu](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html).

Comment: @meditat check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917557/how-to-implement-a-small-popup-with-some-images-on-a-button-click/44917610#44917610

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you can achieve by **QuickAction**  library.

https://github.com/piruin/quickaction
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

[image]

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18831649)

Comment: @DerrickMoeller yes agree with you. thanks for you suggestion i will keep update this.

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing you need is the `PopupWindow`. Its easier to implement and has its custom layout setting option. The `PopupWindow` can be set in custom position as you wish and the idea of implementing a sample copy/paste UI that you are thinking of, can be served with the implementation of `PopupWindow` as well.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077688/3145960) very informative if you want to implement your situation with `PopupWindow` instead of implementing it with context menu.

In the above answer that I mentioned and provided a like to, has a `PopupWindow` which has a `TextView` only. You might implement any custom/complex UI instead of having a simple `TextView` like its shown there.

I hope that helps.

*Update*

As asked in the comment that getting locations of the position of `PopupWindow` can be set dynamically as well. I am referring to another link, so that you can check the implementation from there as well.

[Here's the implementation](https://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html) of using `PopupWindow` in a list.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it in a sec.

Comment: Great! Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: It will not work because I have to get the location of every list item and then have to set the location of popup menu according to that item.And it will become creepy too.is'nt it?

Comment: Nope, I tried, does not work.I am editing what I get from a custom layout.

Comment: Actually you do not have to get the location all the time. The location of the `PopupWindow` can be set dynamically as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164665/discussion-between-meditat-and-reaz-murshed).

Answer (score 1):

So , I wrote below code few year back. You need to make two class first is `PopUp` and second is `TringleView`.

> PopUp :- Make dialog box and open into near your view(where you want
>   to open dialog). **You can change popup bg color**.
>
> TringleView :- Make tringle view or you can say pointed arrow.**You can change pointed arrow bg color**.

```
View contentView = ((FragmentActivity)v.getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_delete_layout,getAttachedRecyclerView(),false);

// this view denote where you click or you want to open dialog near 
PopUp.showPopupOnView(((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(),contentView,view,false);
```

**PopUp.class**

```
public class PopUp  extends DialogFragment {

    protected int targetX;
    protected int targetY;
    protected int targetWidth;
    protected int targetHeight;
    protected Bitmap targetViewImage;
    protected View contentView;
    private SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder fragmentViewHolder;
    private static int bgDrawable = R.drawable.round_corner_white_bg;
    protected static int ONE_DIP;
    private static int arrowBgColor = R.color.border_color;
    private static int arrowWidthMultiple = 25;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ONE_DIP == 0) {
            ONE_DIP = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources()
                                                            .getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AbsoluteLayout parent = new AbsoluteLayout(getActivity());
        parent.setId(R.id.parentLayout);
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.fragmentViewHolder = createViewHolder(view);
        bindView(fragmentViewHolder);
    }

    protected SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder createViewHolder(
                                                                View fragmentView) {
        return new SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder(fragmentView, contentView);
    }

    private void bindView(SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder vh) {
        if (fragmentViewHolder != null) {
            setupTargetDummyView(vh);
            boolean showOnTop = shouldShowOnTop();
            setupArrow(vh, showOnTop);
            setupContent(vh, showOnTop);
        }
    }

    protected void setupContent(SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder vh, boolean showOnTop) {
        final int y;
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams arrowParams = (android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) vh.arrow
                                                                                                       .getLayoutParams();
        int measureHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        vh.popupView.measure(measureWidth, measureHeight);
        if (showOnTop) {
            y = this.targetY - vh.popupView.getMeasuredHeight() + ONE_DIP;
        } else {
            y = arrowParams.y + arrowParams.height - ONE_DIP * 2;
        }

        updateAbsoluteLayoutParams(
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.sixty_dp),
                y,
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth() -
                        getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.seventy_dp),
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, vh.popupView);

        vh.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                exit();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupArrow(SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder vh, boolean showOnTop) {
        final int arrowHeight = 15 * ONE_DIP;
        final int arrowWidth = arrowWidthMultiple * ONE_DIP;
        vh.arrow.setDirectionAndColor(showOnTop ? "down" : "top", vh.popupView.getContext().getResources().getColor(arrowBgColor));
        final int x = (int) (targetX + targetWidth / 3 - arrowWidth / 2);
        final int y = targetY + (showOnTop ? -arrowHeight : targetHeight);
        updateAbsoluteLayoutParams(x, y, arrowWidth, arrowHeight, vh.arrow);
    }

    private void setupTargetDummyView(SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder vh) {
        vh.targetViewDummy.setImageBitmap(targetViewImage);
        updateAbsoluteLayoutParams(targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight, vh.targetViewDummy);
    }

    protected void updateAbsoluteLayoutParams(int x, int y, int width, int height, View view) {
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.x = x;
        layoutParams.y = y;
        layoutParams.height = height;
        layoutParams.width = width;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    private boolean shouldShowOnTop() {
        int windowHeight = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
        int windowMid = windowHeight / 4;
        return targetY > windowMid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        this.fragmentViewHolder = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    protected static class SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder {
        protected AbsoluteLayout parent;
        protected View popupView;
        protected TringleView arrow;
        protected AppCompatImageView targetViewDummy;
        protected SmartWorksPopUpViewHolder(View fragmentView, View content) {
            this.parent = (AbsoluteLayout) fragmentView;
            final Context mContext = fragmentView.getContext();
            this.popupView = content;
            this.arrow = new TringleView(mContext);
            this.targetViewDummy = new SmartWorksAppCompactImageView(mContext);

            this.parent.addView(popupView);
            this.parent.addView(arrow);
            this.parent.addView(targetViewDummy);
            this.parent.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            content.setBackgroundResource(bgDrawable);
        }
    }

    public static PopUp showPopupOnView(FragmentManager fm, View contentView, View targetView, boolean showTargetView) {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        targetView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        PopUp fragment = new PopUp();
        fragment.targetX = location[0];
        fragment.targetY = (int) (location[1] - TypedValue
                                                        .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25,
                                                                targetView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        fragment.targetWidth = targetView.getMeasuredWidth();
        fragment.targetHeight = targetView.getMeasuredHeight();
        fragment.contentView = contentView;
        fragment.show(fm, "offer");
        return fragment;
    }

    public void exit() {
        dismiss();
    }

    public static void setArrowBackgroundColor(int color) {
        arrowBgColor = color;
    }

    public static void setArrowWidthMultiple(int arrowWidth) {
        arrowWidthMultiple = arrowWidth;
    }
}
```

**TringleView.class**

```
public class TringleView extends View {

    private String direction;
    private int color;

    public TringleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setDirectionAndColor("right", Color.RED);
    }

    public TringleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setDirectionAndColor(attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "direction"), Color.RED);
    }

    public TringleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDirectionAndColor(attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "direction"), Color.RED);
    }

    public void setDirectionAndColor(String direction, int color) {
        if (direction != null && !direction.equals(this.direction) || this.color != color) {
            createTriangleDrawable(direction, color);
        }
    }

    private void createTriangleDrawable(String string, int color) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(30,  MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(20, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        Path path = new Path();
        if (string == null) {
            string = "right";
        }
        if (string.equals("top")) {
            path.moveTo(0, height);
            path.lineTo(width / 2, 0);
            path.lineTo(width, height);
        } else if (string.equals("left")) {
            path.moveTo(width, 0);
            path.lineTo(0, height / 2);
            path.lineTo(width, height);
        } else if (string.equals("right")) {
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(width, height / 2);
            path.lineTo(0, height);
        } else if (string.equals("down")) {
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(width / 2, height);
            path.lineTo(width, 0);
        }

        path.close();
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, width, height));
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        setBackground(shapeDrawable);
        this.color = color;
        this.direction = string;
    }

}
```

**edit_delete_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <sis.com.smartworks.widget.SmartWorksTextView
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallest_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="Share"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_unselect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <sis.com.smartworks.widget.SmartWorksTextView
            android:id="@+id/reportSpam"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallest_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="Spam"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_unselect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/three_dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/three_dp"-->
            <!--android:background="@color/white"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp" />-->


        <sis.com.smartworks.widget.SmartWorksTextView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallest_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            app:swFontName="robotoNormal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/edit"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_unselect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/three_dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/three_dp"-->
            <!--android:background="@color/white"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp" />-->

        <sis.com.smartworks.widget.SmartWorksTextView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallest_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:paddingRight="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_unselect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <sis.com.smartworks.widget.SmartWorksTextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallest_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/select_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Result**

[image: ![enter image description here]

So if you want to make view as horizontal then you need to make horizontal layout according to your requirement. So can do this task to change your `edit_delete_layout.xml` which your putting into `contentView` then pass  to `Popup class method`.

**Note:- You can customise popup class according to your requirement and I know this code having so many deprecated view so you can update yourself.**

Comment: for me my code achieve your goal but it depend on you how you can implement at your end . Now its up to you. If you want to change popup location then you need to change on pop up class where we set popup location through target view which we passing while sending xml.

Answer (score 0):

To show compact contextual menu you need to create `ActionMode` for the `Menu`, let me show you how:

> > Suppose your action menu XML have delete, copy and forward actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_copy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_menu_copy"
        android:title="Copy"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_menu_delete"
        android:title="Delete"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_menu_forward"
        android:title="Forward"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

> > Create your action menu in your Activity

```
//Global variable in Activity/Fragment to manage close the menu
private ActionMode mActionMode;

//Action mode callbacks
//Contextual Action bar -  for showing delete/copy/... on action bar
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contextual_action, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Called each time the action mode is shown.
    // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
    // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                //Do the delete action 
                //mAdapter.resetSelection();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the TAB
                //showToast "Deleted successfully"
                return true;
            case R.id.action_copy:
                //mAdapter.resetSelection();
                MyClipboardManager.copyToClipboard(ChatDetailActivity.this, mAdapter.getSelectedMessageText());
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the TAB
                //showToast "Text copied to clipboard"
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
        //mAdapter.resetSelection();
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Closing menu first if it's visible rather than doing the back press action  
    if (mActionMode != null && mActionMode.getMenu().hasVisibleItems()) {
        mActionMode.finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //Closing menu
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

*Set the callback to the global action mode variable

```
mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

*Set title to the menu

```
mActionMode.setTitle("Menu title");
```

*Invalidate the menu after settings value

```
mActionMode.invalidate();
```

> > Style to manage compact contextual menu

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

    <!--CONTEXTUAL action MODE-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <!--ActionMode background color-->
    <!-- <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
    <!--To Overlay existing toolbar, NOTE We are not using android: to let it work everywhere-->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/AppActionModeStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_24dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <!--ActionMode background color-->
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <!--ActionMode text title color-->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionModeTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionModeTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: Have you tried to implement it? Let me know where you have doubt?

Comment: I tried to implement but puzzled in styling.I attached an image to my question,please have a look on it.

Comment: So you don't want like Whats app done on item selection in chat screen?

Comment: Ohh I see, your required UI image. I think then this will work for you https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/custom-layout-popup-window-in-android/

Comment: I also did something like this, but by using Dialog instead of popupmenu.But thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Actually dialog opens in complete window where you can open this custom layout popup menu window at the given position.

Comment: Yup look at mine answer.I also did so.I get the position where the view is touched and show the dialog.