# Android - What is this component?

Tags: android, components

I saw a component in an application which shows a small pop-up with a textView when we tap on a button, but the pop-up disappear when we scroll through the page. The pop-up is displayed just under the button, with an arrow in the direction of the button.

I don't know what it is. Please tell me at least the name of the component or a link to an article of android developer's documentation.

Comment: it will be good if you upload screenshot

Comment: @Muhammad Younas I can't, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @Peterhdd No, it's a type of pop-up that can be displayed everywhere in the screen, that appear when you tap on a button and disappear when you scroll or tap on another place

Comment: Hmm, I think this is what he wants: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow :D

Comment: @Peterhdd no, I know fab and toast, and it isn't. It can appear everywhere on the screen, where you tap on the button. It is "linked" to the button

Comment: @Càphêđen Yes it is! Could you write it as an answer, I would be able to validate it.

Comment: @Tim241 you can refer to that post. No need a duplication here. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several libraries which can popup tooltips given a view as the anchor. Hope these help you!

1. Android ToolTips (with Play Store demo, requires min SDK version 15)

   https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips
2. Simple Tool Tip (Requires min SDK version 8 only)

   https://github.com/xizzhu/simple-tool-tip
3. ViewTooltip (Requires min SDK version 14)

   https://github.com/florent37/ViewTooltip