# android tooltip for imageview to show "pinch to zoom"

Tags: android, android-studio, tooltip, android-imageview, pinchzoom

android tooltip for imageview to show "pinch to zoom", i am done with TouchImageView it is working very good, but i want to show user that image is able to zoom-in and zoom-out.

the tooltip will show on start activity with message "pinch to zoom" how to do that, thanks in advance.

Comment: why not show a simple toast

Comment: toast it will not fulfill requirement, and it will look not good.

Comment: Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21153189/6454463) to display the tooltip. Hope it works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Initial tips for android application**

You can use my library for this approach. Let me know if it is suitable for you or maybe you get any issues with it. 
https://github.com/mpetlyuk/initial_tips

Comment: yes this library is perfectly working for me thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, today was the first release of this library. It means that if you meet any troubles, please, create an issue in the repository - I will try to fix as soon as possible. Starts are welcome! :)

Comment: still there is no issue but if i found then i will definitely tell you