# how to show dialog below the button android

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-dialogfragment

how can we achieve further dialog in design

on click it show like like with top right arrow below button

if i click below bottom button then dialog should open above the button with bottom right arrow

**following is the design**

[image]

note that button is in the recyclerview

please help thanks

Comment: Try with a popup menu, [something like this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu)

Comment: @SatoshiTazu sorry not helpful

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - [Popup window with tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow)

Answer (score 0):

use this library

> ```
> implementation "com.github.skydoves:balloon:1.3.3"
> ```

```
val balloon = createBalloon(requireContext()) {
        setArrowSize(0)
        setWidth(BalloonSizeSpec.WRAP)
        setHeight(BalloonSizeSpec.WRAP)
        marginRight = 8
        autoDismissDuration = 7000L
        setBalloonAnimation(BalloonAnimation.FADE)
        setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                requireContext(),
                R.drawable.curve_white_back
            )
        )
        setLayout(R.layout.layout_menu_shop_filter_sort)
        setIsVisibleOverlay(true)
        setOverlayColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.bg_overlay_menu))
        setOverlayShape(BalloonOverlayRoundRect(8f, 8f))
        setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
    }

    balloon.showAlignBottom(binding.sort, yOff = 16)
```

Comment: how to get id of particluar view access under layout...beacuse i tried but i dint get id click access by doing this ->  balloon.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.button_edit)

Comment: setonclick before ballon.show() . balloon.getContentView().findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sort_newest).setOnClickListener {
            ................
        }

Comment: if you want to catch your custom button click action:
xml : android:tag="tvNextTag" | 
kotlin : balloon.getContentView().findViewWithTag<TextView>("tvBackTag").setOnClickListener { }