# How do you create a customized popup menu in Android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

Sorry, I am new to Android app development. I don't know how to create popup menu to look like in the picture. I want an arrow to point to the three dots that is clicked.
The three dots is an ImageView, and it is in a CardView. And the CardView is in a RecyclerView.

[image]

Comment: Possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66346691/4221943

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this popus is a [ContextMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu). [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#FloatingContextMenu) you can find official guide for Menus, with some sample, also in [HERE](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-context-menu-with-examples) some article about feature with GIFs